# Load JSON record(s) with ember-data 1.0 beta.2

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

with the 0.14 version I loaded JSON data like this:

App.store.adapterForType(App.User).load(App.store, App.User, data)

, but that's no longer working. Is there a way for it in the new version?

Answer (score 0):

The ember.js guides were updated:

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/pushing-records-into-the-store/

store.push() is the way to do it.